# Search NSString in line from file

Tags: ios, nsstring, substring

Is it possible to make a function that searchs a string for an exact substring so that it will only 'return true' if the exact string if found, not as part of a larger word?

```
NSString* search = @"tele";
NSString* stringOne = @"telephone";
NSString* stringTwo = @"tele phone";
NSString* stringThree = @"phone tele";
```

What I mean is: Is it possible to search for a string in a way that the NSString 'search' would be found in strings Two and Three, but not One?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following function in the NSString class:

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach is to append blanks (or whatever your separators are) to front and rear of both strings, then do the search.

Comment: That would be preferable. What would the code be to do that? I have tried a couple of different ways, but all of them give me errors.

Comment: `search = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ",search];` then `stringX = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ",stringX];`, then `NSRange range = [stringX rangeOfString:search];` then `if (range.location == NSNotFound) then NSLog(@"We didn't find%@", search);` .

Comment: actually, its cool. using angela's method i can see if the substring found is the first five letters of the larger string, and that has the desired effect